# How to set IP Address for Client in C with WinSock2

Tags: c, winsock2

My computer has 2 IP addresses for 2 Ethernet cards. `192.168.0.1` is a server, but how to set `192.168.0.2` as client in `C` with `winsock2`. By default client is always `192.168.0.1`.

Comment: You can use `bind`.

Comment: I can use bind to set Address for Server, but with client how can do this?

Comment: @Yarmouk `bind()` works the same for both servers and clients. You `bind()` a server before listening. You can `bind()` a client before connecting.

Comment: solved! Thanks god you are here!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call `bind` before `connect`, to give client a specific IP address or port.

```
sockaddr_in service;
service.sin_family = AF_INET;
service.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.0.2"); // bind to specific IP address
service.sin_port = 0; // not to specify port number

iResult = bind(ListenSocket, (SOCKADDR *) &service, sizeof (service));

// then call connect()...
```

Comment: solved! Thanks!!!

Comment: @Yarmouk Glad it helped. You can *accept* my answer if it solves your problem. :-)

Comment: Rather than fixing te port to 27015, why not just set it to 0?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Good point. Updated the answer.